# Permutations of subsets with certain properties

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $1 \le k \le n$ be integers and let $S_k$ be the set of all $k$-size subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. I am interested in conditions on $n$ and $k$, such that there exists a permutation $\pi$ of $S_k$ such that the consecutive sets of $S_k$ according to $\pi$ have at least $1$ element in common (including the last and the first set). Also, have such objects been studied, and do they have names?

For example, consider $n = 5$ and $k = 2$. Then, consider the following permutation of $2$-size subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ (where I omit set brackets and commas for simplicity):
$$12, 23, 34, 45, 51, 13, 35, 52, 24, 41.$$

However, I don't think there exists such a permutation for $n = 4$ and $k = 2$.

(cross posted on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716272/permutation-of-combinations-with-a-certain-property))

Comment: There is one for $n=4$ and $k=2$, isn't there? This should follow from the fact that Johnson graphs have Hamiltonian cycles (so not only can we guarantee that consecutive sets have at least $1$ element in common, we can make them have $k-1$ elements in common). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

Comment: When $n=4$ and $k=2$, the sequence 12, 13, 14, 34, 23, 24 works. As @SamHopkins suggests, such sequences always exist when $2\le k\le n$. When we require $k-1$ elements in common, they are sometimes referred to as Gray cycles for combinations; see Section 7.2.1.3 of Donald E. Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, volume 4A for a discussion of how to generate such sequences with a computer efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy way to generate such things. Suppose that $k\geqslant 2$, because for $k=1$ this is obviously impossible. List all the $k$ element subsets containing $n$, starting with one that also contains $1$ and ending with one that also contains $n-1$. Next, list all the remaining subsets containing $n-1$, ending with one that also contains $n-2$. Then all the remaining subsets containing $n-2$, ending with one that also contains $n-3$. Continue this way until the last subset has to be $\{1,\dots,k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a construction that works for $k=2$ and arbitrary $n$.

Start with $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\dotsc,\{1,n\}$.
Then do $\{n,2\},\{n,3\},\{n,4\},\dotsc,\{n,n-1\}$.
Then $\{n-1,2\},\{n-1,3\},\{n-1,4\},\dotsc,\{n-1,n-2\}$.
And so on, to $\{5,2\},\{5,3\},\{5,4\},\{4,2\},\{4,3\},\{3,2\}$.